# Bootstrap 3 navbar-fixed-top not working on mobile

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

My setup is slightly more complicated than the bootstrap demo.  I have my navbar below the fold.  Once the navbar is scrolled into place I then add the 'navbar-fixed-top' class via jquery.  It works beautifully on desktop.  But, it's not working on mobile.

Below is the code once the navbar has been scrolled into place.  Unfortunately, the navbar isn't staying fixed.  Am I missing something?

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="mobile-nav-expand"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/pagename.aspx"><img src="/img/my-logo.png" /></a>
            <div class=" class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav visible-sm visible-xs">
                <li class="text-center mobile"><a href="/pagename.aspx">link</a></li>                    
                <li class="text-center mobile"><a href="/pagename.aspx">link</a></li>
                <li class="text-center mobile"><a href="/pagename.aspx">link</a></li>
                <li class="text-center mobile"><a href="/pagename.aspx">link</a></li>
                <li class="text-center mobile"><a href="/pagename.aspx">link</a></li>
                <li class="text-center mobile"><a href="/pagename.aspx">link</a></li>  
                <li class="text-center mobile">
                    <br />
                    <b>ADDRESS</b><br />
                    Street<br />
                    City, State 12345</span>
                </li>                       
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-xs">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle disabled" data-toggle="dropdown" href="/pagename.aspx">link <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="/directory/pagename.aspx">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/directory/pagename.aspx">link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/pagename.aspx">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="/pagename.aspx">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="/pagename.aspx">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="/pagename.aspx">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="/pagename.aspx">link</a></li>                        
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Fixed elements are sketchy on mobile devices (especially iPhones). Many will have the fixed element scroll with the page then snap back into position, which is less than ideal.

Comment: Works fine if I don't use jQuery to add the navbar-fixed-top.